# Spanish to English and English to Spanish dictionary for Dictionary app?

Tags: macos, language, dictionary

For quite a while now, I have been looking for English and Spanish conversion dictionaries (both ways) for Apple's native Dictionary application. So far I have not had any success.

Is there any free, decent quality solution such as "New Oxford American Dictionary" and "Dictionnaire de l'Académie Française"?

Any links or information would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The latest MacOS versions already include Spanish dictionaries which can be enabled in preferences in the Dictionary.app (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>).

The answer below is for converting and installing third-party dictionaries from other popular formats.

To create a dictionary for the built-in OS X Dictionary.app you will first need [pyglossary](https://github.com/ilius/pyglossary/) (`pip3 install pyglossary`) to convert to AppleDict format from the input format such as *ABBYY Lingvo DSL*, *Babylon BGL*, *Stardict IFO*, *AARD Slob* etc (see [supported formats](https://github.com/ilius/pyglossary/#supported-formats)).

Once you generate the AppleDict source XML, you'll need the **Apple Dictionary Development Kit** to create the native binary files for the Dictionary.app.

Proceed as follows:

#### Installing dependencies

1. Install **Xcode command line tools**:

```bash
xcode-select --install
```

2. Install the **[Additional Tools for Xcode](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Auxiliary_Tools_for_Xcode_7/Auxiliary_Tools_for_Xcode_7.dmg)** from https://developer.apple.com/download/ (search with  )— you'll need to login with your iCloud or Apple Developer account. Mount the DMG file by double-clicking it in Finder, and copy the folder **Dictionary Development Kit** to **/Developer/Extras** (as root, use this if you want compatibility with `Makefile`'s generated by pyglossary) (or to `~/Developer/Extras` as a regular user as pointed out by [richard-möhn](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/301542/richard-m%C3%B6hn) — ❗️ in this case you'll need to manually edit the `Makefile` to point to the correct location of the `Dictionary Development Kit` folder):

```bash
mkdir -p ~/Developer/Extras
cp -r '/Volumes/Additional Tools/Utilities' ~/Developer/Extras
```

3. Install Python 3 via [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) (OS X comes with Python 2.x preinstalled):

```bash
brew install python3
```

4. Install pyglossary and dependencies:

```bash
pip3 install -U lxml beautifulsoup4 html5lib PyICU prompt_toolkit python-lzo
```

#### Performing the Conversion

1. Convert the source dictionary (in the example below, Babylon BGL) to AppleDict Source:

```bash
pyglossary --read-options=resPath=OtherResources --write-format=AppleDict webster.bgl webster.xml
```

2. Compile the generated AppleDict sources to OS X Dictionary.app binary files. Pyglossary creates the AppleDict sources in a subfolder named the same as the source file.

---

> <sup>**OPTIONAL**: By default the dictionary name will be derived from the file name of the input file. If you want to modify the name to something else then open the `Makefile` in a text editor, and set the title in the DICT_NAME variable (make sure you include the quotes).</sup>

```bash
cd webster ### subdir name is derived from the source file
make && make install
```

> <sup>**NOTE**: `make` can take significant time if the dictionary is big. For huge dictionaries it can take over 10 minutes.</sup>

`make install` copies the generated dictionary to `~/Library/Dictionaries`.
Now if you restart the Dictionary.app and and open preferences (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>) the new dictionary will appear in the list. Click the checkbox to enable it.

Other formats, for example ABBYY Lingvo DSL require more steps. Here is a [wrapper script for DSL to AppleDict conversion](https://gist.github.com/glowinthedark/da0a026ce0fb691e418c306abc67e525).

There are also literally hundreds of dictionaries available in DICTD, Stardict and ABBYY Lingvo DSL formats.

#### See also:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/DictionaryServicesProgGuide/prepare/prepare.html
- https://github.com/ilius/pyglossary/blob/master/doc/apple.md

Comment: Hi ccpizza, thank you very much for your answer, which is applicable, since i made it work like this in a similar case, using my linux distribution of choice, a few month back. For OSX it works as well!

Comment: I have switched from `.rst` to `.md`. Simply opening the project in your browser will show you the RAEDME file: https://github.com/ilius/pyglossary

Comment: `sudo` is not necessary for adding the Auxiliary Tools for Xcode if you put them in `~/Developer/Extras`.

Answer (score 3):

Look at this link: [clasqm's virtual home](https://web.archive.org/web/20190117192444/http://clasquin-johnson.co.za/michel/mac-os-x-dictionaries/index.html). Here you can find the requested "eng-esp / esp-eng" dictionaries.

Answer (score 2):

As a follow-up to ccpizza's answer, here's what you need as of today:

- Auxiliary Tools for Xcode: http://developer.apple.com/downloads
  You need an Apple Developer account to get that.
  Once you downloaded it, you can just create a new folder at /Developer/Extras and copy the Dictionary Development Kit folder from the Auxiliary Tools there.
- Python. This might be preinstalled.
- beautifulsoup. Fire up a Terminal and launch this command:
  `sudo easy_install beautifulsoup4`
- pyglossary: https://github.com/ilius/pyglossary

Now you can download a dictionary in any format pyglossary can read. All English - X Babylon dictionaries are here: http://www.babylon.com/free-dictionaries/languages/english

Now do what ccpizza said. I had to change the command a bit to

```
python pyglossary.pyw --read-options=resPath=OtherResources --write-format=AppleDict webster.bgl webster.xml
make
make install
```

Note that the output name (in this case "webster") will be the dictionaries name in Dictionary.app's toolbar; I used Spanish.xml for the Spanish dictionary. The last command will automatically install the dictionary file, so you can then enable it in Dictionary.app's preferences.

Comment: Thank you as well Alex, for the additional information. Much appreciated!!

Comment: @Alex: i didn't include the dependencies into the answer because they are listed in the Readme files that come with `pyglossary` and Apple auxiliary tools, but it's good to have them here. Btw, the actual URL Aux package is http://developer.apple.com/downloads. I think that installing `Command line tools for Xcode` is also required, but cannot say for sure. There is also a Readme in the `Dictionary Development Kit` folder - it has the up-to-date instructions about compiling and folder locations, which is useful since Apple changed a bit the directory structure in the latest OSX versions.

Comment: Oops. I didn't notice that in the README file, I used compiler warnings to find out what I was missing :/ ^^  

It did take me a while to find the free Babylon dictionaries for download, so that was another part of the reason for this post. - Also, thanks for correcting my Apple Developer link :)

Answer (score 1):

Starting with at least El Capitan, Apple provides one of these:

[image]