# How can I add an Old English dictionary to Dictionary?

Tags: dictionary

Is there a way to add an [Old English dictionary](http://bosworth.ff.cuni.cz/) to the Dictionary app?  I would like to three-finger-tap a word that's Old English and have it translate it for me.

For pure adventure I want to read [Beowulf](http://legacy.fordham.edu/halsall/basis/beowulf-oe.asp) in its original Old English form.  I was all excited to use Dictionary to help me through each word, and was kinda surprised when it didn't know practically any word in it at all.

If I open Dictionary and search a word (such as HWÆT), it does actually return some related words because their *origin* is the Old English word.

Any ideas?

Comment: Dictionary app?

Comment: Command + Space, type Dictionary.  I don't know any other way to load it except to three-finger tap a word. :)

Comment: Control plus click on a word should give you a dialogue to look it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding dictionaries is possible.  Finding the one you want may not be. See https://web.archive.org/web/20190218202438/http://clasquin-johnson.co.za/michel/mac-os-x-dictionaries/

For info on creating dictionaries for dictionary.app, see

[How can I create a dictionary for Mac OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/80099/how-can-i-create-a-dictionary-for-mac-os-x/80110#80110)

[How to add wiktionary as a source to the default dictionary.app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/122494/how-to-add-wiktionary-as-a-source-to-the-default-dictionary-app)

Comment: It would be better if you describe in sufficient detail how the material from these links answer the question in case the links get broken or the material in them changes. Meanwhile, the top link already appears to be broken.