# How to add wiktionary as a source to the default dictionary.app?

Tags: dictionary

How to add wiktionary to dictionary.app?

For older versions of OS X, there is a method available here [Dictionary.app: how to change from wikipedia.org to wiktionary.org](https://discussions.apple.com/message/20339757). But in the latest system, there are only one field available, as mentioned in the last post.

Comment: I just had a look at Apple's developer documentation and it looks like it wouldn't even be possible to have someone code it for you. I might be wrong on that but it doesn't seem like it is intended for Internet based dictionaries, rather bundles of offline files. (E.g. I have one for English/German)

Comment: A command-line tool that might be used in a solution: [PyGlossary](https://github.com/ilius/pyglossary/). It converts dictionary files between various formats, and it supports writing to the AppleDict Source (XML) format. It supports more formats than [DictUnifier](https://github.com/jjgod/mac-dictionary-kit). An example of how to use it: [converting a Babylon BGL-format dictionary for use with Dictionary.app](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/119166/21473).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [DictUnifier](https://github.com/jjgod/mac-dictionary-kit) to convert any StarDict format dictionary into a mac format dictionary.  You can then download wiktionary in StarDict format here:

http://www.dictinfo.com/

Extract the 7z file with Keka or similar.  You will get three files, a .ifo, a .dictz, and a .idx.

Drag the resulting .ifo file onto the DictUnifier drop location and it will convert and import it into your Dictionary.  You can then go into preferences and check the new dictionary and drag it into the right position for how you want results.

Now you have offline wiktionary access in every language that is available at that dictinfo site (Gobs of them!!).

Comment: Awesome! But it seems to take forever to convert on my laptop. Could you please upload the converted files?

Comment: In [another question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/146373/21473), someone claimed that DictUnifier gets stuck in an infinite loop when trying to follow these steps. An answer to that question theorized that DictUnifier might be broken on newer versions of macOS. As of now, the [latest version](https://github.com/jjgod/mac-dictionary-kit/releases) of [DictUnifier](https://github.com/jjgod/mac-dictionary-kit) is still version 2.1, originally released in 2010.