# Wiktionary in Apple Dictionary app

Tags: dictionary

I have been trying to add Wiktionary as one of the sources of Mavericks’s Dictionary.app but I could not. I have been following the instructions in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/142004) to the question [“How to add Wiktionary as a source to the default Dictionary.app?”](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/122494/how-to-add-wiktionary-as-a-source-to-the-default-dictionary-app) but the DictUnifier app gets stuck indexing the content. Or at least it takes forever… I left the program running the whole night (more than 10 hours in that situation) and nothing happened.

Does anyone know where I can get a Wiktionary version ready to use in Dictionary.app on Mac?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has changed quite a lot in their new OSX version. And as you see on the DictUnifier-website, the tool only was updated to support Lion in the newest version.

> Support Mac OS X 10.7 "Lion"

So Mavericks isn't supported at all, which I think is the root of the problem.

Comment: Are you telling me that if I was Lion user I would be able to do the transformation? That is pretty sad.

Comment: At least that's what I interpret from the owners website.

Comment: Well, most of the times if it can run on Lion, it can run on Mavericks...

Comment: Not all the time like you see it here.