# How to install .dict.dz/.index files to OSX dictionary.app

Tags: dictionary

I have a dictionary that consists of a `dictionary.dict.dz` and `dictionary.index` files. How can I install this dictionary for use with OSX dictionary app (running Mavericks)?

It works fine with GoldenDict, but I'd prefer to have this dictionary amongst the rest.

DictUnifier, which I have used to install a few other dictionaries, doesn't recognize the file.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your input files are in the DICTD format. This can be converted to AppleDict XML source and then compiled for use with the OSX built-in dictionary using [pyglossary](https://github.com/ilius/pyglossary/#supported-formats) as described at https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/119166/66812.