# Are there tools/ a 'simple' process for converting a .dict file into something the macOS Dictionary app can install?

Tags: software-recommendation, dictionary

I have a bunch of different versions of the same specialist English language dictionary (basically, .dict, .dict.dz/ stardict.)

I want to convert this into something I can install on the macOS Dictionary app, but I've drawn a blank. What are the best tools to do this, and is there someone with the patience to outline the process?

Comment: Does https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/41894/37797 answer your question? This provides step-by-step instructions for converting dictionaries from a variety of formats to AppleDict.

Comment: Really kind of you – that looks like exactly the kind of thing I was after. It looks like the 'Additional Tools for XCode' aren't available anymore, though... I'll have a hunt.

Comment: This doesn't work, sadly.

Comment: What exactoy doesn't work? I was able to download  'Additional Tools for XCode 15.3' from http://developer.apple.com/downloads, they still include the Dictionary Development Kit.

Comment: I found the Dictionary Development Kit yesterday.... but I haven't been able to compile the dictionary from the .dict or the .xml. I'm not clever enough to work out why it keeps failing, sadly. I've tried everything I know with my (pretty limited) grasp. I tried hiring a freelancer on freelancer.com and he couldn't do it either. It's kind of infuriating. It's a comparatively simply task that ought to take about an hour including troubleshooting and... I am defeated.